# imported FacebookSDK and yet missing class runtime exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have the following android layout xml:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/authButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

However I get runtime error:
[image]

which can even be seen in the Graphical editor:

[image]

But I don't get why,
as I have imported the FacebookSDK properly (i think)

and when I do cmd + right click on the XML I get to the right class implementation
[image]

`package com.facebook.widget;

public class LoginButton extends Button {`

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Download facebook sdk from this link and import https://www.facebook.com/campaign/landing.php?campaign_id=282184128580929&placement=Android_SDK&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fresources%2Ffacebook-android-sdk-current.zip

Comment: i don't get this. I have download from FB oficial site. why mine doesn't work?

Comment: because the sdk u downloaded does not have loginbutton.class in facebook/src/com/widget/facebook/   thats why its giving class not found exception

Comment: but it does. I even mentioned the right click on the xml leads to the right class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently done Facebook Android Integration from [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) link.

> When i imported FacebookSDK into my project, I got error in console of
>   android-support-v4.jar mismatch. Because i have 2
>   android-support-v4.jar files in FacebookSDK Project and in my Project.
>   Due to Which an error is coming at runtime of ClassDefNotFound. So I
>   Deleted one of the jar file.

Check this out if it helps you.

> And the SDK provided on the link was not working well. So tried out
>   with different SDK from [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads) Link. And got success with SDK
>   3.0.2.

I hope this will help you out.